# validate a yaml file locally with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, yaml

Is there a good way to validate a YAML locally ? 
I have several YAML issues in production env on deploy, like

```
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/78bed61832ff72ff3426
```

Not very informative, I would like to know the file this happens in. 
Is is possible to improve debugging yaml issues a bit more?

Also im not sure why this happens only in production and not in development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing a rake task to do this:
save as /lib/yaml.rake for example ( .rake ! not .rb)

```
namespace :yaml do

desc "Test YAML files"
task :check => :environment do
  require 'yaml'

  d = Dir["./**/*.yml"]
  d.each do |file|
    begin
      puts "checking : #{file}"
      f = YAML.load_file(file)
    rescue Exception
      puts "failed to read #{file}: #{$!}"
    end
  end
end
end
```

Comment: You should not rescue from `Exception` but from `StandardError`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from my experience tracking down bugs in YAML is not easy. Online tools like [yamllint](http://yamllint.com/) usually give similar error messages like the ones Psych provides.

Only thing I could advise is: check diff from local/production YAML files and see what has changed.